# If $B$ is a commutative domain, $Aut(B)$ acts on $Der(B)$ by conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

I'm reading *Algebraic Theory of Locally Nilpotent Derivations* by Gene Freudenberg, and I don't understand what's meant on the line

- $Aut(B)$ acts on $Der(B)$ by conjugation: $\alpha \cdot D = \alpha D \alpha^{-1}$.

Here $B$ is a commutative $K$-domain, $Aut(B)$ is the group of ring automorphisms of $B$ and $Der(B)$ is the set of derivations of $B$.

I understand that $\alpha D \alpha^{-1}$ is the conjugation of the map $D \in Der(B)$ by the map $\alpha \in Aut(B)$. However, I don't know what $\alpha \cdot D$ means. What is $\cdot$ ? I would suppose it is the regular group operation of $Aut(B)$ (the composition of functions), but what does the equality $\alpha \circ D = \alpha \circ D \circ \alpha^{-1}$ say? Also, wouldn't there a problem since $Der(B)$ is a very different set from $Aut(B)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha\cdot D$ is here defined as $\alpha D\alpha^{-1}$. In order to substantiate the statement "group (or other structure)  $G$ acts on set (or other structure) $X$" one has to exhibit a map $G\to \operatorname{Aut}(X)$, for which the notation $g\mapsto (x\mapsto g\cdot x)$ is common and wide-spread.